# Pass Json Object from Play! framework to HighCharts JS

Tags: json, highcharts, playframework-2.0

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaTodoList

Using the above tutorial as a reference, I have created an application which sends data from the model to view via the Application controller.
I have managed to display the model(Tasks) as a high chart. The code is here.

```
public static Result format(){      
    return ok(views.html.frmt.render("Visualize it",Task.all()));
}
```

This goes to this view page.
http://ideone.com/ycz9ko

Currently, I use scala templating inside the javascript code itself. Refer to lines 9-14 and lines 20-24.This unelegant style of doing things is not really optimal.

I want to be able to accomplish the above using Json instead.

```
public static Result jsonIt(){
    List<Task> tasks = Task.all();
    return ok(Json.toJson(tasks));
}
```

My Qns are how to send the JSON objects to a view template. 
And how to parse it into a Highcharts format. Is there some standard procedure to do this ? Or else I have to write my own method to do this ?
It'll great if someone can show me a code snippet. Also I would prefer a post not using Ajax. I would just want to know how to do this first.

I also found this stackoverflow post useful.[how to parse json into highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499431/how-to-parse-json-into-highcharts). However, it didnt answer the part about converting from Play format to Highcharts format.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass a `json object` to your template, instead you might do an ajax call from your client side javascript (your template) and get json response that you could use futher in javascript code to build a chart. For example :
You have some path that is bind to your controller `jsonIt()` like so /chartsdata/json
then using `jquery shorthand` for ajax request:

```
var chart_data = $.get('/chartsdata/json', function(data) {
   return data;
});
```

now you can use a `chart_data` that is `an array of objects` where each object represents a Task, in your further javascript code to build a chart.

Comment: http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=428                                                 I followed the above the link as well to get a thorough understanding.